# Google Play Console how do publish my app after beta

Tags: google-play-console

I have uploaded an app the play console and it is now on the Play Store but says (Beta). I was just wondering how do I publish the full version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You promote the Production Track. Please note that if you are enrolled on a testing track you will still see Beta next to your app name, however if you use another Google Account that is not enrolled, you should not see Beta.

Comment: Yep, it was because I was using my account, but when I removed myself from the beta testing it fixed it. Thank you

Comment: Great to hear! Please mark this as the accepted answer :-)